# Joomla: Override Category Blog output multiple times?

Tags: joomla, components, overriding

Yes. I want to override output of Category Blog component to 2 different display styles.

For first style, i copied and edited blog_item.php & blog.php in [mytemplate]/html folder. Then i choose template style from dropdown in backend of my category blog. That's worked. The display of category blog change as i expected.

But if i want to create another style and use in another category blog. How could i do ? And how to i named my files ( I tried blog_1.php, blog_item_1.php ) but only see my first style display in backend.

I'm using joomla 2.5.

Please help me. Thank you very much !

=================================================================================

[UPDATED]
I solved this issue. Here my solution:

1. Clone my template to [my_template_2]
2. Go to [my_template_2]/html/com_content/category then edit blog.php, blog_item.php as my needs.
3. Go to backend, at my category blog menuitem, i assigned [my_template_2] as its template style.

Then it worked. Both my category blog have its own style.

This maybe not very good solution because i have to use multiple templates, but at this time it's quite enough for me.

Thank you, stackoverflowers.

=================================================================================

[UPDATED 2]

Now, with multiple template styles, I could create unlimited styles for my category blog component within just only one template. That's very much better.

Comment: I have found this, as you get the "Template Style" drop down it would make sense to be able to have multiple overrides with just different names, $name.php and $name_item.php you need to keep the item as there is a method call. But this is set in the CP not the menu item :(

Comment: Related question: [Creating multiple layout overrides for category blog layout](http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/8971/creating-multiple-layout-overrides-for-category-blog-layout)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you may know, joomla doesn't let developers make different styles for its components.

I think you have to list all menus which are made by "category blog component" in template managing page and let users set each menu style at there.**
and at blog.php, check template setting and then load customized style...

---

** you have to develop a custom field element which list all "category blog component" menus.

*** you can use this code to accessing template parameters in component's template :

```
$app        =& JFactory::getApplication();
$template   = $app->getTemplate(true);
$paramsTemplate = $template->params;
$style = $paramsTemplate->get('style');
```

Comment: Hey man. Now I understand what you said. I created 2 styles for my template, and used a template parameter to tell what style i'm currently in. So, as you said, in blog.php, I load my custom style depend on that template parameter. Thank you. This is much better than multiple templates solution.

Comment: "As you know"? Ofcourse Joomla let's you override layouts and use multiple over rides.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use multiple styles. What you need is to use alternate layouts and alternative menu layouts.
For alternative menu layouts in the html/componentname/category folder of your template make a new style with a unique set of names similar to the way blog already provides an alternative to category list in the article category layout folder.  Also make a new xml file for each layout that you make, with a matching name.

When you create your menu item you will now get these alternatives along with your other normal choices. Just select the one you want.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the learnings above here is my code for the /templates/mytheme/com_content/category/blog.php

And then in the Global Configuration > Article Manager Options > Category choose Blog as the override/ layout.

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

JHtml::addIncludePath(JPATH_COMPONENT.'/helpers');
$pageclass_sfx = trim($this->pageclass_sfx);

// so pick it on the page class in menu item
if (isset($pageclass_sfx) && $pageclass_sfx != '') {
    echo $this->loadTemplate($pageclass_sfx);
} else {
    echo $this->loadTemplate('default');
}
```

I can add multiple elseif if something else is needed, or it will look for 'blog_' . $this->pageclass_sfx . 'php'. It is always beginning blog_ as thats coded into the com_content. The old blog i moved to blog_default.php and blog_default_item.php